# EC_GENERIC_REDIRECTVIEW Doesn't works only on production server and after a 30sec load

Tags: java, websphere-7, websphere-commerce, wcs

I've a case I whould like to understand.
Here is two different way to redirect to a page after a Command job:
(On WCS7)

First:

```
TypedProperty rspProp = new TypedProperty();
rspProp.put(ECConstants.EC_VIEWTASKNAME, ECConstants.EC_GENERIC_REDIRECTVIEW);
rspProp.put(ECConstants.EC_URL, "AddressBookForm");
setResponseProperties(rspProp);
```

Second:

```
TypedProperty rspProp = new TypedProperty();
rspProp.put(ECConstants.EC_VIEWTASKNAME, "AddressBookForm");
setResponseProperties(rspProp);
```

If the treatment of the command take less than 30 seconds, both solution works.
BUT if the command takes more than 30 seconds, the first way display a "Connection reset" browser error page (same on FF, IE, Chrome, ...).

I've try to reproduce on my local toolkit, but even if the process take more than 30sec, I can't reproduce. (I've try until 20min :/ ).

I would like to understand why the execution time can broke the RedirectView?
And why it's only happening on a live server?

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the execution of RedirectView is breaking in the case of prod servers only. But as you said above Redirect flow will take more time than normal forward view.

PFB url of same topic. Let me know whether this helped you in resolving your problem,

http://deepakpadmakumar.blogspot.com/2012/05/forward-view-and-redirect-view-in-wcs.html